# Rspec can't stub method for class

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class that puts some info into a database.  Here is the method from the class I'm testing:

```
def load(configs)
  opts = { access_token:  configs['token'],
           api_endpoint:  configs['endpoint'],
           web_endpoint:  configs['site'],
           auto_paginate: configs['pagination']}

  client = Octokit::Client.new(opts)   

  repos = client.org_repos(configs['org'])
  repos.each do |r|
    Project.create(name: r.name)
  end

   rescue NoMethodError
  raise GitConfigError, 'put something here yet'
  end
end
```

I successfuly can test if it raises an error, however I don't know how to go about testing if the data is being put into the database correctly.  I can't seem to find any resources on it either.  Though, I did test the model in another spec.  Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stub both methods - the API call and the save into the database. The API call should be tested in the gem. And `create` is tested in Rails. You can assume that both methods work like described in the docs. Edge cases (like failing calls to creates cause of failing validations) should be tested separately.

I would write the spec like this:

```
context '#load' do
  let(:options) { token: 'foo', ... }
  let(:repos)   { [{ name: 'bar'}] }
  let(:client)  { instance_double(Octokit::Client, repos) }

  before do
    allow(Octokit::Client).to_receive(:new).and_return(client)
    allow(Project).to_return(:create).and_return(true)
  end

  it 'initializes the API client' do
    thing.load(options)

    expect(Octokit::Client).to have_received(:new).with(
      access_token: options[:token],
      # ...
    )
  end

  it 'stores records received from the API' do
    thing.load(options)

    expect(Project).to have_received(:create).with(name: 'baz')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if by 'if the data is being processed correctly' you mean if it got saved in the database you could do something like

```
it "saves Project in db" do
   expect { subject.load([{name: "a"}, {name: "b"}]) }.to change(Project.count).from(0).to(2)
end

it "saves it with correct data" do
  subject.load([{name: "a"}, {name: "b"}])
  expect(Project.all.map(&:name)).to eql ["a", "b"]
end
```

or if the `Octokit::Client.new(opts)` is an external api you could use something like webmock or vcr to stub out api calls

```
it "calls external api and creates Project based on this data" do
  stub_request(:get, "http://api.example.com/cats").and_return([{name: "a"}, {name: "b" }])
  subject.load()
  expect(Project.all.map(&:name)).to eql ["a", "b"]
end
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for.   Is there a way to mock it rather than actually putting it into the database?

Comment: Depending on what's your approach on testing. I rather save something in db and test it's "behaviour" then stub something out. Example: if I write a test that checks if it saves it in db then I can exchange api provider without breaking specs. However I have no clue on what are you working and can't tell you what's best for you :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can go with 
`expect_any_instance_of(Octokit::Client).to receive(:org_repos).and_return([{name: "a"}, {name: "b"}])` You can find more information on [rspec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)